# Django: How to make one-to-one relation with auth login and custom profile model?

Tags: python, django

I've implemented google login to my project, logs in correctly and makes a new row in the database for the user, but does not make a profile. I have one-to-one relation between the user and the profile, how can i add profile for the google logins? I'm getting error `UserProfile matching query does not exist.` when i try to view my profile on the page.

This is the view for the profile page:

```
class ProfileView(views.View):
    template_name = 'profile/profile.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = UserModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).get()
        profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user.pk).get()

        context = {
            'profile': profile
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

the url:

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile-page'),
```

and the template:

```
<li class='text-black text-xl mx-2 py-1.5  rounded-full bg-slate-300 shadow-2xl hover:bg-slate-400'>
    <a class="px-3 py-1.5" href="{% url 'profile-page' pk=request.user.pk %}">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user">
       </i>
    </a>
</li>
```

I can get the error not to show but when i try to edit the profile it cannot do it since it has no relation with the profile model.